# Linux Mint's keyboard shortcuts utility restricts certain key combinations

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, settings

Currently in Linux Lite I have `Shift + Space` setup to run a script on my desktop. As you can see in the images below the keyboard utility in Linux Lite is only too happy to let me use that shortcut, but Linux Mint (Cinnamon) balks at the idea:

**Lite:**
[image: Keyboard configuration screenshot in Linux Lite]

**Mint:**
[image: Keyboard configuration screenshot in Linux Mint]

In Lite I don't have a problem with this hotkey. If I'm holding shift for ALL CAPS then the hotkey does fire when I hit space, but it doesn't make typing "impossible" and I'm willing to deal with this little snafu.

**Is it possible to override this or other hotkey restrictions in Linux Mint?** Perhaps I can modify a config file somewhere to set the hotkey directly without the use of a Gui?